# Сброс Сlass при смене/генерации div

Tags: javascript, html, css

Имею следующую структуру, две панели управления, панель генерируется в соответсвии с выбором и интерфейсе

1

```
<div class="groupby">
    <label id="list" class="">Detalied</label>
    <label id="group_g" class="">Group by G</label>
    <label id="group_date" class="active">Group by Date</label>
</div>
```

2

```
<div class="groupby">
    <label id="list" class="active">Detalied</label>
    <label id="group_date">Group by Date</label>
    <label id="net">Group by Network</label>
    <label id="count">Group by Country</label>
    <label id="group_g">Group by G</label>
</div>
```

подключил следующий js для смены класса по нажатию на label(подкрашивает выбранную функцию)

```
$(document).on('click', 'div label', function(){
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active')
});
```

Не силен в js, просьба, подсказать, как реализовать сброс позиции выбранного label при переключении между 2 панелями, чтобы при смене сбрасывалась или возвращался в позицию `<label id="list" class="">Detalied</label>`
Благодарю!

Comment: $(".groupby label").removeClass("active") ?

Comment: @Crus
можете подсказать, как корректно составить? переключения панелей происходит следующим путем
<div id="switch_s_m">
    <label class="" style="display: inline-block;">
        <input class="" type="radio" checked="">s</label>
    <label class="active" style="display: inline-block;">
        <input class="" type="radio">m</label>
</div>

Comment: вроде получилось, таим способом:
$(document).on('click', 'label input', function(){
   $(".groupby label").removeClass("active")
   $("#list").addClass("active")
})

Comment: добавьте воспроизводимый пример - я посмотрю